# No access to Azure Storage Account which has virtual network only access, despite a succesful Point2site connection to that virtual network

Tags: azure-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

I want to restrict access to my Azure storage account to selected networks only (please see image).

*Current network restriction setting*
[image]

My current set up is as follows:

- I have an Azure Storage account, with blob containers and tables.
- Only selected networks can access this storage account (please see the first image above). I've selected the gateway subnet (I've tried to add other subnets within the same virtual network, to no avail).
- I have selected a virtual network call. All service endpoints for this network are set up correctly ('storage-service endpoint' is 'succesful'). The subnet involved is gateway subnet.
- I also have a virtual gateway which is placed inside this virtual network. With (of course) the gateway subnet assigned to it.

*Subnet endpoint permission*

[image]

- I have a point2site VPN connection (using Azure VPN client) to connect to this virtual network from my local machine (see image below).
- This connection has been set up as well, using Active Directory as authentication method. All seems correctly working.
- The virtual gateway to which the VPN connects, can see the active connection (see image below)

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, so any help is very much welcome!

Regards,R.

**VPN connection details**
I have a point2site connection to the virtual network that is granted access to this storage account (see images below).

The point2site connection looks good (see image below), but I still can't access the storage account.

*Current connection in azure VPN client*
[image]

*Current view of active connection to Virtual Gateway that connects to this Vnet.*
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: try with IP address of network interface of private endpoint :     \\Private IP Address\Filesharename   : Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/22842/cannot-access-storage-account-file-share-over-p2s.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario that can be possible with setting the private end point in storage account and azure VPN client.

you need to create and configure a Private End Point under the subnet you have the storage account exists.
Go to 'Private Endpoint Connection' under settings of storage account in azure portal as below:

[image]

Connected with Vnet using Azure VPN client .

[image]

Now you can map network drive on this pc using this format

```
\\Private IP Address or FDQN \Filesharename
```

[image]

[image]

For me there is one blockage.it **error: Unable to reach the Azure storage account via port 445**. I can’t add port 445 in my system if you have port number 445 you can be able to access the file share if not add port 445 so the SMB traffic over this port.

Note: Disable the firewall/ anti-virus temporarily installed on your computer.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for your elaborate answer. I'm not trying to use any private endpoints and synchronize folders on my local machine.
What I do want is to be able to (after connecting the VPN client):
1) Browse the blobs and tables in the azure portal for the particular storage account
2) Access the blob and tables from scripts (e.g. powershell, python) from my local machine.

I want to do this while networkaccess is restricted to Vnets only, And that I've connected (using the p2s VPN) to (one of the vnets)  that has access to the storage account.

How do I configure the IP addresses?

Comment: Use the same above method but you can mention the IP address of your restricted VNET that you might have created under Networking->Firewall and Virtual Network->Selected network-> add existing network

Comment: Where do I mention this IP address?

Comment: use on Map network drive on your PC.